# Anaconda 環境を VSCode でも使えるようにしたい

Tags: python3, vscode, anaconda

#### 前提・実現したいこと

下記の記事を参考にVS codeでanaconda環境からクローンした設定でPythonコードを書きたいと考えています．

[Python環境構築(Anaconda + VSCode) @ Windows10 【2020年１月版】](https://qiita.com/manamana/items/38e963ce04f24de4bbe4)

この内のtask.josonを作成するところでつまづいております．
質問内容としては下記のとおりです．

task.jsonを格納するディレクトリ．上記のページで言うtest.pyと同じディレクトリにすればいいのか．それとも作成された際に格納されているディレクトリから移動しなくていいのか
1.commandにはpython.exeのディレクトリを書くとのことですが，argsにはどのファイルのディレクトリを書いたらよろしいでしょうか．
ご教示いただければ幸いです．
よろしくおねがいします．

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

「Ctrl + Shift + B」(ビルドタスクの実行コマンド)を実行すると、タスクがないという警告メッセージが表示されます

#### 該当のソースコード

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "python build",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "${config:python.pythonPath}",
            "args": ["${file}"],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

#### 補足情報（FW/ツールのバージョンなど）

Python 3.8
VSCode 1.58

Comment: これらの記事の方が新しい版数に対応してそうなので参考にしてみては？ [【Windows】VS Code + Anaconda で Python の開発環境を用意する](https://qiita.com/eyuta/items/d0ece5ae147109db1308), [【最新】VSCodeでAnaconda3(Python)を実行する方法(Windows)](https://tech-diary.net/vscode-anaconda3-python/), [WindowsでPython、Anaconda、VSCodeのインストールとPython開発環境を構築する方法](https://www.nblog09.com/w/2020/11/22/windows-python/)

Comment: 「Anaconda 環境を VSCode でも使えるようにしたい」ではなく、「Anaconda 環境でVSCodeを使えるようにする」ではいけませんか？ANACONDA.NAVIGATORで環境を生成し、その環境でANACONDA.NAVIGATORからVSCodeを使うことができます。